# How to optimize considering 5 highest values of a model.Var() in PYOMO Python

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to run an optimization with PYOMO. My variables and my objective function areas follow.
I want in my objective function to get the  highest values for my variable L in model.L. I used model.L.get_values().values() but it is not working.

How can I do it? I have tried to put my variables in a dataframe before the optimization but it did not work.

Thanks.

```
# Define model parameters
model.T = Set(initialize=df.hour.tolist(), ordered=True)
model.Rmax = Var( within=PositiveIntegers )
model.Smax = Var( within=PositiveIntegers )
model.Q = Var(model.T) 
model.Z = Var(model.T, domain=NonNegativeReals)  
model.L = Var(model.T) 


# Objective function
model.costs = (sum(df.loc[t, 'Price'] * model.L[t] for t in model.T) + Bcosts + 
           sum(max(model.L.get_values().values()))*demand_charge)

model.objective = Objective(expr=model.costs, sense=minimize)

# Solve the model using (GLPK open source solver in python)
results = SolverFactory('glpk').solve(model)
```

Comment: the `max()` function is non-linear, so you can't have that in your objective expression.

Comment: ok, what would you do then? Thanks

Comment: You can add a variable `x` and some constraints saying that `x` must be as large as all of your `model.L` variables (`x >= model.L_t for all t`). Then you can use `x` in place of the max